# Can place but not destroy blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I can't break any blocks on my Minecraft even though I'm not on adventure mode. Even when I'm on creative, I can't break them. I can build perfectly fine but I can't destroy anything, not even a mere painting.

I've tried restarting my computer, deleting my world, taking my resource pack off, re-creating it, restarting my Minecraft. I even tested if it was my mouse.

Comment: Check your options to see if your "break block" button has been rebound or unbound somehow. Other than that I'm not *quite* certain why this would be happening.

Comment: This can also happen on a multiplayer sever in the spawn area.  Try walking for a bit in any direction and then break.

Comment: Are you in single player or multiplayer (as mascone suggested).

Answer (score -2):

If you're in multiplayer and you cannot break blocks, walk a little distance, because this may not apply away from the spawn area.

If you're in singleplayer, check if you have enabled Touchscreen mode in settings, and turn it off if it isn't already.